# Contents section not displaying correctly using achemso package

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning, achemso

I'm having an issue with the achemso package whereby the contents is not displaying correctly. The two issues are

i) 'References; is displaying beneath a horizontal line and not next to the relecant section number which should be 3.
ii) The number 3 in the references section is above the horizontal line

Below is a minimum working example.

```
\documentclass[journal=jacsat,manuscript=communication]{achemso}
\setkeys{acs}{articletitle = true}
\SectionsOn
\SectionNumbersOn

\title{Title}
\author{A. N. Other}
\affiliation[Latex]{Latex University}
\email{other@latex.org}

\begin{document}

\begin{filecontents}{references.bib}
@article{ref1,
    title = {Paper Title},
    volume = {70},
    journal = {Nature},
    author = {Smith, J. H.},
    year = {1942},
    pages = {1--31},
}
\end{filecontents}

\tableofcontents
        
\section{Section 1}
Text\cite{ref1}
\section{Section 2}
    
\bibliography{references}
    
\end{document}
```

[image: Image of the issue]

Answer (score 0):

This is not the default of a communication type document for J. Am. Chem. Soc. but it will solve  the issues.

[image: c]

```
\documentclass[journal=jacsat,manuscript=communication]{achemso}

\setkeys{acs}{articletitle = true}
\SectionsOn
\SectionNumbersOn

\makeatletter % added <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
\AtBeginDocument{%
\def\bibsection{\acs@section*{\refname}}
}

\makeatother

\usepackage{kantlipsum}% dummy text <<<

\title{Title}
\author{A. N. Other}
\affiliation[Latex]{Latex University}
\email{other@latex.org}

\begin{document}

\begin{filecontents}{references.bib}
@article{ref1,
    title = {Paper Title},
    volume = {70},
    journal = {Nature},
    author = {Smith, J. H.},
    year = {1942},
    pages = {1--31},
}   

\end{filecontents}

\tableofcontents

\section{Section 1}
1.  \kant[1-2]

\section{Section 2} 
2. \kant[2-3]   

Text\cite{ref1} 

\bibliography{references}
    
\end{document}
```

The **default** is set with `\SectionNumbersOff`, (because) the reference list goes as a footnote, and the table of contents can not be used for the same reason. (It also sets `\SectionsOff`).

[image: d]